# Efficient way of querying string and number field from PostgreSQL's json field

Tags: json, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

We have used json field in postgres as we have dynamic fields. Fields can be string or number type only. We have billions of rows in table hence queries are working too slow. We could't add index as we don't aware the field names used in query and queries will be constructed dynamically during run time.

Table design is as follows,

```
id - integer
workspace_id - integer
data - json
created_at - timestamp
updated_at - timestamp
```

Stored data in json field as follows,

```
{"age": 21, "city": "London", "name": "ABC", "test_filed1": "text",...}
```

Example for string field:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
WHERE users.workspace_id = 1 
  AND data ->> 'city' = 'London' 
ORDER BY users.id DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

Example for number field:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
WHERE users.workspace_id = 1 
  AND CAST(data ->> 'age' AS NUMERIC) = 21 
ORDER BY users.id DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

When we are using `->>` operator to get data, it automatically type cast the result to string. For instance, when I get age like `data ->> 'age'` then resulted value will be type cast to `'21'` though it's stored as number value. If we need to check any of number related condition, we need to type cast (as mentioned in example) to check greater_than, less_than though we stored age data in number format in json field. Also for for checking string also it's doing type cast to `::text`.

Since I have stored data in appropriate format (used quotes for string and stored number as number without quotes), is there any better way to get data as stored in DB rather than type cast? So that I can do number related conditions without type cast.

**Note** : I have already added index for workspace_id.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `->>` **always** returns a `text` values - that's how it is implemented (it's not really "casting" the value).

JSON doesn't really have a notion of data types, so there is no operator in Postgres that would yield a different data type when you extract values from a JSON each time you use it. As everything can be represented as `text`, this is what `->>` returns.

This is the price you pay for de-normalizing your data model.

However equality comparisons can be done differently (when you cast the column to `jsonb` which it should be to begin with).

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
WHERE users.workspace_id = 1 
  AND data::jsonb @> '{"city": "London"}'
ORDER BY users.id DESC 
LIMIT 50;

SELECT users.* 
FROM users 
WHERE users.workspace_id = 1 
  AND data::jsonb @> '{"age": 21}'
ORDER BY users.id DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

The `@>` can make use of a GIN index on the JSONB value, e.g.

```
create index on users (data::jsonb);
```

Obviously this is subject to the usual index usage rules. Not every index that is created is also being used.

(But it would be better to convert the `data` to jsonb to avoid the casting all the time)

Comment: Migrate from json to jsonb is not possible as our code base and table size (more than 400GB) are huge. If there any other approach, please suggest.

Comment: @empr: then you have to live with the casting.